# TabPanel not Render or Show tabs

Tags: extjs

I have a simple app presentation with a set of windows with sencha components. When a event of move previous window or move next window the main controller take the view, clean it and add a new component to view...

```
Ext.define('jsclient.view.main.MainVC', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.main-view',

    config: {
        listen: {
            global: {
                eventNewWindow: 'eventNewWindow'
            }
        }
    },

    eventNewWindow: function (callback) {
        this.view.removeAll();
        this.view.add(callback());
    }
});
```

The problem occurs when i put a panel component that contains a tabpanel, the components paint all window, paints the tabs, but no paint the components that contain each tab. If i exam the components that window create, its was created but not render or showing.

```
Ext.define('jsclient.view.articleCheck.ArticleCheckV', {
    extend: 'Fwk.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.article-check',

    controller: 'article-check',
    viewModel: 'article-check',

    requires: [
        'Fwk.Panel',
        'Ext.TabPanel',
        'jsclient.view.articleCheck.ArticleCheckVM',
        'jsclient.view.articleCheck.ArticleCheckVC',
        'jsclient.view.articleCheck.articlePending.ArticlePendingV',
        'jsclient.view.articleCheck.articleChecked.ArticleCheckedV'
    ],

    cls: 'article-check',
    title: 'Mi ventana**',
    titleAlign: 'center',

    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'fit'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        flex: 1,
        deferredRender: true,
        items: [{
            title: 'Pendientes',
            reference: 'pending',
            xtype: 'article-pending',
            width: "50%"
        }, {
            title: 'Chequeados',
            reference: 'checked',
            xtype: 'article-checked',
            width: "50%",
        }]
    }],

    tools: [{
        type: 'left',
        docked: 'left',
        listeners: {
            click: {
                element: 'element',
                fn: 'goPrevious'
            }
        }
    }, {
        type: 'plus',
        docked: 'right',
        margin: '0 20 0 0',
        listeners: {
            click: {
                element: 'element',
                fn: 'goNewArticle'
            }
        }
    }],

    listeners: {
        click: {
            element: 'element',
            fn: 'prueba'
        }
    },

    constructor: function (config) {
        this.callParent([config]);
    }
});
```

Any code have two file more that helps viewmodel component, i will saw you a example above.

**The View:**

```
Ext.define('jsclient.view.main.MainV', {
    extend: 'Fwk.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.main-view',

    id: 'main-view',

    requires: [
        'Fwk.Panel',
        'jsclient.view.main.MainVM',
        'jsclient.view.main.MainVC',
        'jsclient.view.blockCheck.BlockCheckV',
        'jsclient.view.centerList.CenterListV',
        'jsclient.view.articleCheck.ArticleCheckV',
        'jsclient.view.articleCheck.articlePending.ArticlePendingV',
        'jsclient.view.articleCheck.articleChecked.ArticleCheckedV'
    ],
    viewModel: 'main-view',
    controller: 'main-view',

    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'fit'
    },
    margin: 'auto',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'center-list',
        flex: 1
    }],

    constructor: function (config) {
        this.callParent([config]);

        //Read url params and restore context if needed
        var urlParams = location.search;
        if (urlParams !== '') {
            Fwk.Context.restore(urlParams);
        }
    }
});
```

**The Controller:**

```
Ext.define('jsclient.view.main.MainVM', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.main-view',

    data: {},

    stores: {}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to my problem i doesn't find a solution in the way i'm trying solved... But using a different point of view i can solved.

- My oldest way, create items on a component:

  This solution might be correct but... for **tabpanel** doesn't work. I create a component in viewport (main component) and in this component when a event happend i create a new component.

  ```
  -> Viewport
   |
    -> MainComponent
     |
      -> AnyComponent (event)
  ```

  Using this piece of code i try modified the view main with a callback that return the 
  constructor of new component in **main view**:

  ```
  /*
  * Callback in other view
  */
  callback: function(options){
   return new jsclient.view.mycomponent.MyComponentV(options);
  }
  /*-----------------------------*/
  eventNewWindow: function (callback) {
   this.view.removeAll();
   this.view.add(callback());
  }
  ```
- My new way create items on viewport:

  The new solution is similar but use Viewport instead main component, We need have some
  things clear. Viewport is a set (Array) of views that compete for main view, if not are 
  on main view, the components is on second plane and they not are visible but are init.

  So solution left like that, instead use main component we use viewport:

We create N controller for N view, and when a other view send a global event, the controller catch the event and itself create here on viewport.

```
 Ext.define('jsclient.controller.main.MainController', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

        requires: [
         'jsclient.view.main.i18n.Main_en_EN',
         'jsclient.view.main.i18n.Main_es_ES', 
         'jsclient.view.main.MainV',
        ],

        config: {
         listen: {
           global: {
             eventNewMain: 'eventNewMain'
           }
         }
        },

        eventNewMain : function(options) {
         Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem('main-view');       
        }
     });
```

In the case we need pass argument to component we can do this piece of code:

```
Ext.define('jsclient.controller.articleCheck.ArticleCheckController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

requires: [
    'jsclient.view.main.i18n.Main_en_EN',
    'jsclient.view.main.i18n.Main_es_ES',
    'jsclient.view.articleCheck.ArticleCheckV',
],

config: {
    listen: {
        global: {
            eventNewArticleCheck: 'eventNewArticleCheck'
        }
    }
},

eventNewArticleCheck: function (options) {
    if(options != undefined){
        Ext.Viewport.removeAll();
    }

    Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype: 'article-check',
        options: { block: options }
    });

    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem('article-check');
}
});
```